# Как отправить пакет на другой интерфейс? kernel module

Tags: linux, c, kernel

Пишу модуль ядра для управления маршрутизацией\коммутацией пакетов.

Возник вопрос, на сервере две сетевые карты, они смотрят в две разные сети, мне нужно пришедший пакет на интерфейс №1 отправить на интерфейс №2 с изменением ip адреса назначения, т.к. интерфейсы смотрят в разные сети.

Суть в том, что клиенты обращаются только на интерфейс №1, моя задача перенаправить их пакеты на интерфейс №2, с изменением ip адреса назначения, а ответ, пришедший ответ на интерфейс №2 отправить в интерфейс №1, только уже изменив IP адрес адресата.

Система сама разберется на какой интерфейс отправить пакет или нужно явно указать, что определенный пакет пришедший с интерфейса №1 нужно отправить в интерфейс №2 и наоборот?

```
int main_hook(unsigned int hooknum,  
                  struct sk_buff *skb,
                  const struct net_device *in,//вхоящий
                 const struct net_device *out,
                  int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff*))
{
struct ethhdr *eth;
struct tcphdr *tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
printk(KERN_ALERT"------------ВХОДЯЩИЙ----------------------");
    printk(KERN_INFO "DEV NAME [%s]\n", dev->name);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "TCP FIN-> %u\n",tcph->fin);
printk(KERN_ALERT "TCP SYN-> %u\n",tcph->syn);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "DEVICE NAME -> %s\n",skb->dev);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SOURCE -> %u\n",htons((unsigned short int)tcph->source));
printk(KERN_ALERT "DEST -> %u\n",htons((unsigned short int)tcph->dest));
    printk(KERN_ALERT"------------------------------------------------");
    }
return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

printk(KERN_INFO "DEV NAME [%s]\n", dev->name); показывает [LO], на исходящий пакет [NULL].

Comment: С помощью чего пакеты перехватываете? на каком уровне? Если пакет будет пробегать по стеку ядра, то вероятно он после подмены адресов попадёт на нужный интерфейс после процедуры ядерной маршрутизации. Если же сами отправляете на интерфейс, то кроме адреса подменяйте skb->dev самостоятельно.

Comment: @dsnk на уровне prerouting.

Comment: Тогда позаботьтесь о контрольных суммах, должно само на нужный интерфейс попасть после подмены адреса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написал @dsnk, после подмены адреса система сама отправляет пакет на нужный интерфейс.